# Multi-thread usage in Dymola slow down solution speed

Tags: multithreading, multicore, modelica, dymola

Does using multi-core functionality in Dymola2020x always speed up the solution? My observation is using Advanced.ParallelizeCode=true for a model with DOF~23k; compiling time is comparable with single thread however the solution time with default solver is slower.

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Parallelisation will only result in performance gains in case the system properties allow it.
This seems to be a summary worth reading: https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/decouple-blocks-and-model-parallelisation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-core functionality of a single model does not always speed up execution.

There are a number of possible explanations:

- There are so many dependencies that it isn't possible to parallelize at all. (Look at translation log - this is fairly clear).
- It's only possible to parallelize a small part of the model. (Look at translation log - this takes more time).
- The model uses many external function (or FMUs), and by default Dymola treat them as  critical sections. (See release notes and manual on `__Dymola_ThreadSafe` and `__Dymola_CriticalRegion`).
- In versions before Dymola 2020x you might have to set the environment variable  `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=PASSIVE`. (Shouldn't be needed in your version.)

Using decouple as described in https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/decouple-blocks-and-model-parallelisation/ can help for the first two.

Note that an alternatives to parallelization within the model is to parallelize a sweep of parameters (if that is your scenario). That is done automatically for sweep parameters, and without any of these drawbacks.